# How to know the file's type to save, using QFileDialog

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qfiledialog, qtgui

About pyQt4

I prefer to use the static method for the getSaveFilename in the QFileDialog so that the user sees the Windows/Mac native dialog.

My problem is that if the user doesn't type the file extension the in the save file name (say when selecting an image type to save a file as), then I don't have a way of checking to see what type of file they wanted to save as.

How can I create a dialog to save files with a filter, and how to know which filter the user chose?

For example:

```
files_types = "GML (*.gml);;Pickle (*.pickle);;YAML (*.yml)"
file = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file', '', files_types)
```

With var file I'll have only the file's path, but I'm not sure whats the format that user chose.

So, I wanna know how could I get the extension, or the files type chosen by user.
Is there away to get the selectedFilter using this method?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  Even if I leave the extension off in the save filename, the QFileDialog appends the selected file type extension to the returned filename.  Can you post a little more of your code?  There are various options that affect the returned file.  I wonder if one of those options is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `getSaveFileNameAndFilter()` method:

```
filename, filter = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileNameAndFilter(self, 'Save file', '', files_types)
```

(In [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) however, `getSaveFileNameAndFilter()` does not exist, and `getSaveFileName()` already behaves that way. I'm not sure whether this is also the case for PyQT api version 2, which is the default for Python 3)

Comment: If someone uses PyQt5, then the `getSaveFileNameAndFilter()` method is renamed to `getSaveFileName()`. For example: `file_name, filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save text report', 'myreport.txt',
                                                                 "text (*.txt);;html (*.html)")`  see [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html)

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt5 just use:

```
files_types = "GML (*.gml);;Pickle (*.pickle);;YAML (*.yml)"
options = QFileDialog.Options()
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, 'Save as... File', 'untitled.gml', filter=file_types,options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible.

The only way to do this, is creating a generical dialog, but by another hand you will lost the pretty native windows.

Comment: Not true, it is possible, see my answer.